# at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have values stored in the JSON url and parsing the value from json then displaying in the app.I'm using Async task to get the values from JSONArray and display in the list. when i get the values from server i got error and the json values are

```
[{"name":"John","uuid":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D","major_id":"67889","minor_id":"7032","notification":"Welcome","type":"Website","website":"estimote.com"}]
```

Log:

```
10-16 17:46:38.996: W/System.err(11224): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"notification":"Welcome","uuid":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D","type":"Website","website":"estimote.com","major_id":"67889","minor_id":"7032","name":"John"}] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-16 17:46:38.996: W/System.err(11224):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
10-16 17:46:38.996: W/System.err(11224):    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:484)
```

code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                      jObject = jarray.getJSONObject(0);

                    Log.d("jsonObj_Response: ", "> " + jarray);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jObject.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        //TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_major_id, TAG_minor_id, TAG_notification, TAG_type

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_major_id);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_minor_id);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_notification);



                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_major_id, email);
                        contact.put(TAG_minor_id, address);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you missed a JSONArray

```
  JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
  for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray innerArray = jarray.optJSONArray(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < innerArray.length(); j++) {
              jObject = innerArray.getJSONObject(j);
         }
  }
```

After OP's Edit

```
  JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
  for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jobj = jarray.optJSONObject(i);
        if (jobj != null) {

        }
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error org.json.JSONException: No Value for
at org.Json.JSONOBJECT.get
at org.Json.JSONObject.getJSONArray

Comment: Please check edited JSON value..It's only one JSONArray

Comment: then you have just a for-loop. You don't have also any contacts tag inside your `json` object

Answer (score 0):

jObject = jarray.getJSONObject(0) is a JSONArray, your string has an object within an array within an array ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have two arrays ("[["/"]]") so "jObject = jarray.getJSONObject(0);" fails as it tries to convert "[{"name" ... estimote.com"}]" to a JSONObject but this is a JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

jarray[0] is a JSONarray not a JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

My soluation as follows ,

```
 JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);//Response string is here

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray arr2 = arr.optJSONArray(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length(); j++) {
          jObject = arr2.getJSONObject(0);
     }
 }
```